# ArgumentError in StaticPages

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I had a working pagination but after some changes to the gemfile, all the 
pagination started throwing this error
wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)

The gemfile changes have brought the errors on every class that needs pagination so it could be an issue about how I am handling the gem.
The error is here
Showing /home/ec2-user/environment/homework_helper/app/views/assignments/assignment/_homework_answers_page.html.erb where line #3 raised:

```
  <%= will_paginate @assignments  %> -line  3


      <% @assignments.each do | assignment | %>

      <tr>


gem 'will_paginate',           '3.1.6'
gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap4'


 def homework_answers
   @assignment = Assignment.new
   @categories = Category.all
   @assignments = Assignment.all
   @assignments =  Assignment.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
  end
```

Comment: Try this. Remove the first `@assignments` variable. Then on the second `@assignments` variable do `@assignments =  Assignment.all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)`.

Comment: What changes dod you do to the `Gemfile`? Version updates (from what version to what version)? Please post the full error messages including the stack trace.

Comment: @spickermann here is part of it

Comment: will_paginate (3.1.6) lib/will_paginate/active_record.rb:140:in `select_for_count'
activerecord (5.2.3) lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:225:in `perform_calculation'
activerecord (5.2.3) lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:145:in `calculate'
activerecord (5.2.3) lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb:52:in `count'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this is the exact same problem as described in [this issue](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/issues/400). There is already a [pull request](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/pull/401) to fix this issue, but that PR hasn't been merged for ages.

However, the description of the issue tells that the problem was introduced in version `3.0.7` and that `3.0.6` was good. Therefore I suggest – if possible – to downgrade the `will_paginate` gem to that version.

```
# in your Gemfile
gem 'will_paginate', '<= 3.0.6' # see https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/pull/401
```